# Cannot calculate gradients using theano

Tags: theano

I cannot calculate gradient if I use theano.fft.rfft. Below is a minimal code example which reproduce the problem:

```
import theano.tensor as tt
import theano.tensor.fft

def fft_real(input):
    a = input.dimshuffle('x', 0)
    spec = tt.fft.rfft(a, norm='ortho')
    return spec[0,:,0]

inp = tt.vector('real_n', dtype='float64')
f = fft_real(inp)
cost = f.sum()
g = tt.grad(cost, inp)
```

It gives an error:

```
File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\theano36\lib\site-packages\theano\tensor\elemwise.py", line 197, in __init__
    (input_broadcastable, new_order))
ValueError: ('You cannot drop a non-broadcastable dimension.', ((False, False), [1]))
```

I am using theano version 1.0.2